# SqlAlchemy How to get objects from "child" class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))
    
    children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parents')
    
    
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    name = Column(String(20))

    parents = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')
    
    
    

mother = Parent(id=1, name='Sarah')
c1 = Child(id=22, parent_id=mother.id, name='Alice')
c2 = Child(id=23, parent_id=mother.id, name='Bob')

print(mother.children)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[]
```

As you can see, the result is an empty list. But I want to see `c1` and `c2` objects and get their attributes.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You didn't `.flush()` or `.commit()` any changes from the session

Comment: @roganjosh I haven't created any sessions, because I was playing with classes alone. So sessions are mandatory to get results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to set up a one-to-many relationship between Parent and Child using SQLAlchemy. The issue in your code is that you haven't actually added the child objects (c1 and c2) to the children relationship of the mother object.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))
    
    children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parents')
    
    
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    name = Column(String(20))

    parents = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')
    
    
# Instantiate the objects
mother = Parent(id=1, name='Sarah')
c1 = Child(id=22, parent_id=mother.id, name='Alice')
c2 = Child(id=23, parent_id=mother.id, name='Bob')

# Add the child objects to the parent's children relationship
mother.children.append(c1)
mother.children.append(c2)

# Now, when you print mother.children, it should include c1 and c2
print(mother.children)

# Access attributes of c1 and c2
for child in mother.children:
    print(f"Child ID: {child.id}, Name: {child.name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems that sqlalchemy doesn't resolve the relationships until you flush or commit.  Here are some test cases below.  I thought just adding the objects to the session might change something but it does not.  You can manually connect the relationships before hand if needed.  Ie. placing children in the `children` list as in `test2()`.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
    BigInteger,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship, joinedload


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=False)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')



class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "childs"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))

    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def test1():
    """"""

    with Session(engine) as session:

        mother = Parent(id=1, name='Sarah')
        c1 = Child(id=22, parent_id=mother.id, name='Alice')
        c2 = Child(id=23, parent_id=mother.id, name='Bob')
        # Children and parent(s) are not set.
        assert not mother.children and not c1.parent and not c2.parent

        session.add(mother)
        session.add(c1)
        session.add(c2)
        # Nothing changed.
        assert not mother.children and not c1.parent and not c2.parent

        session.flush()
        # Now children and parent(s) are set.
        assert mother.children and c1.parent and c2.parent

test1()



def test2():
    """"""

    with Session(engine) as session:
        c1 = Child(id=22, name='Alice')
        c2 = Child(id=23, name='Bob')

        mother = Parent(id=1, name='Sarah', children=[c1, c2])
        # Children and parents are now set but their parent_ids are not set.
        assert mother.children and c1.parent and c2.parent and not c1.parent_id and not c2.parent_id

        session.add(mother)
        session.add(c1)
        session.add(c2)
        # Nothing changed.
        assert mother.children and c1.parent and c2.parent and not c1.parent_id and not c2.parent_id

        session.flush()
        # Now children are set and parent ids are set.
        assert mother.children and c1.parent and c2.parent and c1.parent_id and c2.parent_id

test2()
```